# Projected grid water horizon detail

Tags: c++, 3d, geometry, directx-11, hlsl

I'm trying to implement an ocean scene with C++ and DirectX11. Currently I have a projected grid, Gerstner waves and a basic shading. My problem is that when I aim my camera horizontally, so I can see the water horizon, in the distance, the projected grid becomes insufficient, even at high vertex numbers. These screenshots illustrate the problem:

[image: shaded water surface]

[image: wireframe water surface]

I know the cause of the problem is in the concept of the projected grid (the grid is detailed near the camera, rough far from it), but there has to be a best practice to solve this.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think that http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for asking this question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I asked the question there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benedikt Bitterli and joojaa answered my question here:
https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/projected-grid-water-horizon-detail

I chose the laziest solution for now. I calculate an attenuation factor from the distance from the camera in the vertex shader, and I gradually flatten the waves in the distance.

The function:

```
float CalculateWaveAttenuation(float d, float dmin, float dmax)
{
    // Quadratic curve that is 1 at dmin and 0 at dmax
    // Constant 1 for less than dmin, constant 0 for more than dmax
    if (d > dmax) return 0.f;
    else
    {
        return saturate((1.f / ((dmin-dmax)*(dmin-dmax))) * ((d-dmax) * (d-dmax)));
    }
}
```

Here are the results:

[image: shaded]
[image: wireframe]

Answer (score 0):

You should try implementing your "basic shading" algorithm in the fragment shader rather than the vertex shader.